# How to implement a branching strategy with Bitbucket before pushing source code?

Tags: branch, bitbucket

I am working on a project which is based on scrum methodology. We are planning to use Bitbucket as our source repository. We have planned a branching strategy such that, releasing a branch at the end of each sprint and then merging it with main branch. Is there anyway to implement a branching strategy with Bitbucket before putting the source code into Bitbucket?